# How to retrieve new incoming data by polling and feed it back

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, long-polling

Here the method reads the database which has an unique ID with the sequence number which keeps on increasing, since am a beginner in java,can I know how to implement this repetitive polling and check for new incoming message each time.

```
public void run() {
int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<KpiMessage> list = null;
        try {
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();
                incomingMessages.addAll(list);
                System.out.println("waiting 3 seconds");
                System.out.println("new incoming message");
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

//Method which defines polling of the database and also count the number of Queries
public List<KpiMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {
    Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION =  804 and SEQ >" + lastSeq + "order by SEQ DESC");     
    List<KpiMessage> pojoCol = new ArrayList<KpiMessage>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        KpiMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
        pojoCol.add(filedClass);
    }
    for (KpiMessage pojoClass : pojoCol) {
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo1());
        System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo2());
        System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());
    }
    //          return seqId;           
    return pojoCol;
}
```

My goal is to Poll the table from the database and also check for new incoming message, which I can find from the Header field SequenceID in table which is unique and keeps on increasing for new entries. Now my problem is

1.Lets say after I poll the first time, it reads all the entries and makes the thread to sleep for 6 seconds, by the mean time how can I get the new incoming data and Poll it again ?

2.Also how to add the new data ,when it does Polling for the second time and pass the new data to another class.

Comment: please format your code!!!

Comment: please remove not useful comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poller calls fullPoll every 6 secs and passes lastSeq param to it. Initially lastSeq = 0. When Poller gets result list it replaces the lastSeq with max SEQ value. fullPoll retrieves only records with SEQ > lastSeq.

```
void run() throws Exception {
    int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
          List<KpiMessage> list = fullPoll(seqId);
          if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            seqId = list.get(0).getSequene();
          }
          Thread.sleep(6000); 
    }
}

public List<KAMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {
       ...
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION =  804 and SEQ > " + lastSeq + " order by SEQ 
      DESC");     
      .. 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much tried this but still having errors in return type and passing parameters...can you sort this out...  https://gist.github.com/9bab6f82c83ff6fb9c3a

Comment: There's a problem in how get next max sequence, see my update.

Comment: thank you I have got it executed but now, if Its  not doing fullPoll() repeatedly instead its waiting for only new incoming data, how can I achieve this in parallel... I have Updated the code above please give me a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code you may use to get working on. I tried to make it pretty flexible using the Observer pattern; this way you can connect multiple "message processors" to the same poller:

```
public class MessageRetriever implements Runnable {
    private int lastID;
    private List<MessageListener> listeners;

   ...

    public void addMessageListener(MessageListener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener)
    }

    public void removeMessageListener(MessageListener listener) {
        this.listeners.remove(listener)
    }

    public void run() {
        //code to repeat the polling process given some time interval    
    }  

    private void pollMessages() {
        if (this.lastID == 0)
            this.fullPoll()
        else
            this.partialPoll()           
    }

    private void fullPoll() {
        //your full poll code

        //assuming they are ordered by ID and it haves the ID field - you should
        //replace this code according to your structure
        this.lastID = pojoCol.get(pojoCol.length() - 1).getID() 

        this.fireInitialMessagesSignal(pojoCol)
    }

    private void fireInitialMessagesSignal(List<KAMessage> messages) {
        for (MessageListener listener : this.listeners)
            listener.initialMessages(messages)
    }

    private void partialPoll() {
        //code to retrieve messages *past* the lastID. You could do this by 
        //adding an extra condition on your where sentence e.g 
        //select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION = 804 AND SEQ > lastID order by SEQ DESC
        //the same as before
        this.lastID = pojoCol.get(pojoCol.length() - 1).getID() 

        this.fireNewMessagesListener(pojoCol)
    }

    private void fireNewMessagesListener(List<KAMessage> messages) {
        for (MessageListener listener : this.listeners)
            listener.newMessages(messages)
    }

}
```

And the interface

```
public interface MessageListener {
    public void initialMessages(List<KAMessage> messages);
    public void newMessages(List<KAMessage> messages)
}
```

Basically, using this approach, the retriever is a runnable (can be executed on it's own thread) and takes care of the whole process: does an initial poll and continues doing "partial" polls on given intervals.

Different events fire different signals, sending the affected messages to the registered listeners, and those process the messages as they want.

Comment: thank you so much,I have blowing my mind for day... I will run it & come back to you...

Comment: @Babu No prob. Make sure this model fits your needs, it may be an overkill for what you need to do tho, in which case Evgeniy Dorofeev solution may be better suited.

Comment: @arsemax I am able to do polling for the first time and get new message, but am stuck here by how to pass this to another class and feeding back to Poll once again.... My code is not able to repeat polling after an interval... please check my updated code...